# How do I obtain data from different files and combining into one array in python?

Tags: python, export-to-csv, analysis, typing

I have to collect data to prove my hypothesis that typing with your dominant hand is faster than typing with your non-dominant hand. I have written the code below that gives the participant a random word and then they have to copy it. The code will time how long it takes to type each word and then save that data to a new file. For each participant that is tested a new CSV file will be created.

Now I need to write another script that will find the average for each hand for each participant and then create a single array containing the averages so I can create a graph to prove whether or not my hypothesis is true. How would I go about getting data from different files and combining it into one array?

My Script:

```
import random
import time

name = raw_input('Enter name: ')  # get some name for the file
outfile = file(name + '.csv', 'w')  # create a file for this user's data

# load up a list of 1000 common words
words = file('1-1000.txt').read().split()

ntrials = 50

answers = []
print """Type With Dominant Hand"""
for i in range(ntrials):
    word = random.choice(words)
    tstart = time.time()
    ans = raw_input('Please type ' + word + ': ')
    tstop = time.time()
    answers.append((word, ans, tstop - tstart))
    print >>outfile, 'Dominant', word, ans, tstop - tstart  # write the data to the file
    if (i % 5 == 3):
        go = raw_input('take a break, type y to continue: ')

print """Type With Nondominant Hand"""      
for i in range(ntrials):
    word = random.choice(words)
    tstart = time.time()
    ans = raw_input('Please type ' + word + ': ')
    tstop = time.time()
    answers.append((word, ans, tstop - tstart))
    print >>outfile, 'Nondominant', word, ans, tstop - tstart  # write the data to the file
    if (i % 5 == 3):
        go = raw_input('take a break, type y to continue: ')

 outfile.close()  # close the file
```

Sample results from above script:

```
Dominant sit sit 1.81511306763
Dominant again again 2.54711103439
Dominant from from 1.53057098389
Dominant general general 1.98939108849
Dominant horse horse 1.93938016891
Dominant of of 1.07597017288
Dominant clock clock 1.6587600708
Dominant save save 1.42030906677
Nondominant story story 3.92807888985
Nondominant of of 0.93910908699
Nondominant test test 1.69210004807
Nondominant low low 1.13296699524
Nondominant hit hit 1.15252614021
Nondominant you you 1.22019600868
Nondominant river river 1.42011594772
Nondominant middle middle 1.61595511436
```

Answer (score 1):

This may seem like another language if you're not familiar with numpy, but here's a solution that takes advantage of it (notice the lack of loops!)

For testing, I created a second user data file, with each entry incremented by 1 second.

```
import glob
import numpy as np

usecols = [0, 3] # Columns to extract from data file
str2num = {'Dominant': 0, 'Nondominant': 1} # Conversion dictionary
converters = {0: (lambda s: str2num[s])} # Strings -> numbers

userfiles = glob.glob('*.csv')
userdat = np.array([np.loadtxt(f, usecols=usecols, converters=converters)
                    for f in userfiles])

# Create boolean arrays to filter desired results
dom    = userdat[..., 0] == 0 
nondom = userdat[..., 0] == 1 

# Filter and reshape to keep 'per-user' layout
usercnt, _, colcnt = userdat.shape
domdat    = userdat[dom   ].reshape(usercnt, -1, colcnt)
nondomdat = userdat[nondom].reshape(usercnt, -1, colcnt)

domavgs    = np.average(domdat,    axis=1)[:, 1]
nondomavgs = np.average(nondomdat, axis=1)[:, 1]

print 'Dominant averages by user:    ', domavgs
print 'Non-dominant averages by user:', nondomavgs
```

Output:

```
Dominant averages by user:     [ 1.74707571  2.74707571]
Non-dominant averages by user: [ 1.63763103  2.63763103]
```

If you're going to be doing a lot of analysis, I'd highly recommend getting your head around numpy.

Comment: It keeps giving me an IndexError: list index out of range and points to line 7 userdat = np.array([np.loadtxt(f, usecols=usecols) for f in userfiles])

Comment: OK, I've edited the solution so that your original file format will work. I suspect you didn't add the extra column of '0' or '1' after the first column; now you don't have to.

Comment: One of the most regretted "mistakes" I've made with Python was waiting too long before turning Numpy into my main everyday tool. Once you get it, things get A LOT easier... And some more become possible!

Answer (score 0):

```
persons = ["billy","bob","joe","kim"]
num_dom,total_dom,num_nondom,total_nondom=0,0,0,0
for person in persons:
   data = file('%s.csv' %person, 'r').readlines()
   for line in data:
      if "Nondominant" in line:
         num_nondom+=1
         total_nondom+=int(line.split(' ')[-1].strip())
      elif "Dominant" in line:
         num_dom+=1
         total_nondom+=int(line.split(' ')[-1].strip())
      else: continue
dom_avg = total_dom/num_dom
nondom_avg = total_nondom/num_nondom
print "Average speed with Dominant hand: %s" %dom_avg
print "Average speed with Non-Dominant hand: %s" %nondom_avg
```

Fill the "persons" array with the names of your subjects and then do what you please with the data.

PS. Heltonbiker noted your idea and added it. Also fixed the newline bug by adding in strip.

Comment: It keeps giving me a ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.90565299988\n'for line 9 total_nondom+=int(line.split(' ')[-1])

Comment: Replace that for `line.split(' ')[-1].strip()`. The strip will remove the `\n` character and then you can turn it to int. I liked this answer, but IT SHOULD INCLUDE A LOOP SHOWING HOW TO HANDLE MORE THAN ONE FILE!

Answer (score 0):

```
def avg_one(filename):
    vals = { 'Dominant': [], 'Nondominant': [] }
    for line in input:
        hand, _, _, t = split(line.strip())
        vals[hand].append(float(t))
    d = vals['Dominant']
    nd = vals['Nondominant']
    return (sum(d)/len(d), sum(nd)/len(nd))

data = []
for f in os.listdir():
    if f.endswith('.csv'):
        data.append(avg_one(f))

doms, nondoms = zip(data)

print "Dominant: " + repr(doms)
print "Nondominant: " + repr(nondoms)
```

This presumes that there are no other .csv files in the same dir that have a different format (and would fail parsing).  And this needs more error checking in general, but it gets the idea across.